# Find the altitude of the triangle given the equation of sides

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> The sides of a triangle are on the lines $2x+3y+4=0$, $ \ \ x-y+3=0$, and $5x+4y-20=0$. Find the equations of the altitudes of the triangle.

Should I find the vertices first? Or is there a direct way? Actually, I tried finding the vertices, using the substitution method but I find it hard to turn it into an equation.

Comment: Yes, there is a direct way.  But in any case you need to be comfortable solving simultaneous linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan:** For the given equation of line as $$ax + by + c = 0 \tag{1}$$ you can find the general equation of perpendicular lines as $$bx - ay + d = 0 \tag{2}$$
for some $d\in \mathbb R$. Now, you just need to find the values of $d$.

In order to find $d$, find the vertex point (the intersection of the other two sides than $(1)$) and plug that into $(2)$ (because the perpendicular line should pass through that vertex). Since $a$ and $b$ are known values you can derive the value of $d$ from there.

---

**Solution:** Take the third equation, for example. $$5x+4y-20=0 \tag{1}$$
Then, the general equation of perpendicular lines is $$4x-5y+d = 0 \tag{2}$$
Now, we will find the intersection of the other two lines than $(1)$.
$$\begin{cases}
2x + 3y + 4 = 0 \\
x - y + 3 = 0\end{cases} \implies (x,y) = \left(-\frac{13}{5} , \frac{2}{5}\right)$$
Now plug this into $(2)$ to get
$$4\left(-\frac{13}{5}\right) - 5 \left(\frac{2}{5}\right) + d = 0 \\ d=  \frac{62}{5}$$
Thus, the equation of altitude to the side which is given by $(1)$ is $$\boxed{4x-5y + \frac{62}{5} = 0}$$ You can find the other two altitudes with the same method.

Comment: he asked that we have to find vertices or not

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi With the way I've shown, yes, you will need to find the vertices. As OP said that he was struggling with "turning that into equation", I also provided an easy way to do this task.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. Finally, I was able to get the equations I'm struggling to find earlier.

Answer (score 0):

$$r:2x+3y+4=0,\;s:x-y+3=0,\;t:5x+4y-20=0$$
The set of all lines passing through the intersection point $r\cap s$ is
$$\mathcal{F}:a(2x+3y+4)+b(x-y+3)=0\tag{1}$$
$$\mathcal{F}:(2a+b)x+(3a-b)y+4a+3b=0$$
To find the one perpendicular to $t:5x+4y-20=0$ we use the condition
$$5(2a+b)+4(3a-b)=0\to b=-22a$$
plug this value in the equation $(1)$ and get

$a(2x+3y+4)-22a(x-y+3)=0$

simplify $a$ and get the first height equation
$$20 x-25 y+62=0$$
In a similar way we can get the other two equations
$$27x-18y+46=0;\;7x+7y-16=0$$